# Text in permalink

Tags: permalinks, templates

I've this kind of permalink for `post` type : `/widgets/%category%/%postname%/`
And the problem is that when going to `/widgets` url (`http://mysite.com/widgets`) a not found page error (404) is displayed. What is the default template ?

I've `index.php`, `archive.php`, `category.php`, `single.php` with some custom templates.

And another thing that i think i should say is by creating a page with the slug of `widgets` and assigning it to a template, that error gone away and the content of that template comes up.

Answer (score 0):

There is no template for "/widget". Templates are about content types and not URL fragments.

IMO your page hack is totally legit. Another way to handle this is to have a widgets category which is the parent of all other categories and change your permalink structure to /%category%/%postname%/